# Break a column of dictionaries to new columns

Tags: python, dataframe

In my dataframe, there is a column of dictionaries:

| ID | name | value | stats |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  | {'mean': 154.0, 'median': 154.0, 'std': 0.0} |
|  |  |  | {'mean': 131.19, 'median': 93.68, 'std': 53.04} |

I need to break down that column as new columns

| ID | name | value | mean | median | std |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  | 154.0 | 154.0 | 0.0 |
|  |  |  | 131.19 | 93.68 | 53.04 |

I tried to use `pd.json_normalize` as follow:

```
df2 = pd.json_normalize(df['stats'])
df2
```

But this way I lose the indexes in `df2` and can't join them to add new columns to `df`. How should I do it?

Comment: Can you copy the index from `df1` to `df2`?

Comment: Can you please post a complete example with input dataframes that contain the indexes you want to preverse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try applying a pd.Series on each dictionary , it would convert as individual dataframe, followed by merging

```
pd.concat([df, df['col'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1).drop('col',axis=1)
```

other approach

```
df.merge(df['col'].apply(pd.Series), left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer').drop('col',axis=1)
```

Example

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['col'] = [{'mean': 154.0, 'median': 154.0, 'std': 0.0},
             {'mean': 131.19, 'median': 93.68, 'std': 53.04}]
df['some'] =1
```

Prior

```
    col some
0   {'mean': 154.0, 'median': 154.0, 'std': 0.0}    1
1   {'mean': 131.19, 'median': 93.68, 'std': 53.04} 1
```

OUt:

```
    some    mean    median  std
0   1   154.00  154.00  0.00
1   1   131.19  93.68   53.04
```

Comment: This adds a lot of new rows to my dataframe: goes form shape of (2896, 19) to shape=(15564, 21)

Comment: possibly by index mismatch in merging,  would you share snippet of df json data, it would be more clear to apply and check

Comment: I just edited question, can you try checking it